# difference in box-shadow when using position relative

Tags: css, firefox

I'm little surprised with the behavior of box-shadow that if the container is positioned relatively the shadow goes to below but if it isn't positioned (i.e. static position) the shadow appears to front.

```
#main{
  position: relative; /*sets shadow to below the heading*/
}
```

Unsetting relative position sets the shadow to front of the heading:

```
#main{
  /*position: relative; */
}
```

[image]

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fsfg32en/)

Can anyone tell me about this change?

Comment: For me in chrome adding `position: relative;` doesn't change anything, it alway displays under the shadow.

Comment: Just tried in a few browsers. Firefox shows this problem. Chrome and IE do not.

Comment: Oh! yeah, this is only in firefox...

Comment: `position: relative;` to `#main #foo` works for me on firefox - http://jsfiddle.net/fsfg32en/1/

Comment: I need to use position relative to main... and that's not the reason the setting to foo is appearing to front but it's the unseting relative from the main...

Comment: @C-linkNepal , are you working on Firefox Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: relative` should not have an effect there in normal circumstances, because the element with the shadow appears later in the source anyway.

The real problem here, which is not mentioned in the question, is the fact that you're working with `display: table-*` elements. Firefox is known to behave differently from other browsers when using `position: relative` on internal table boxes because there is no defined behavior in such a situation. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position):

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

If your layout relies on stacking contexts to work, such as when you're using box shadows, I advise against using `display: table`.

Comment: +0001) but I want to know why my solution `transform: translate(0, 0);` works on firefox (I've no idea!)? - http://jsfiddle.net/fsfg32en/8/

Comment: @Mary Melody: A transform causes an element to establish a stacking context. When you have a positioned element, and an element that creates a stacking context, if both of them have the same z-index then the one that appears later in the source will be painted in front.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` or `translate(0, 0);` to `#main > div` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsfg32en/7/)**

**or** `-moz-transform: translate(0, 0);` to target only Firefox browser - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsfg32en/8/)**

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    display: table-row;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
}
#main > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /* or transform: translate(0, 0); */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below css rule also.

```
#main > div {
display: table-cell;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
width: 500px;}
```